# iOS Restkit: how to parse nested path

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit

I had a JSON response of this type:

```
{
"d": { "id": "1", "user": "test"}
}
```

which I was parsing with Restkit with the following code:

```
@interface ODataUser : NSObject<ODataObject>

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * id;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * user;

-(NSString*)getId;
-(NSString*)getUser;
@end
```

> RKObjectMapping *map = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ODataUser
>   class]]; [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:  @{    @"id" :
>   @"id",    @"user" : @"user"    }  ];

```
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:map method:RKRequestMethodGET  pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"d" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

However, now my response has changed to something like this:

```
{
"d": { "results": [ {"id": "1", "user": "test"} ] }
}
```

How can I reflect those changes on the response on my code?

Comment: [Take a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890105/confusion-setting-mapping-in-rkobjectmapping-rest), may be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your response descriptor to use:

```
keyPath:@"d.results"
```

as this will navigate into the `d` dictionary to get the `results` array and process all of the dictionaries it contains.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Give details - errors, crash log? If neither, turn on trace logging and show the contents.

Comment: Sorry, my error was related to something else. Your solution worked.